# Disappearing meshes

Tags: c++, directx

I encountered a strange DirectX problem. When I move my camera, some of the models starts flickering or some of the model parts just disappear like in screenshot bellow. Any ideas why? Could it be related with vertex buffer?

[image]

Comment: It could be z-fighting or it could be something else - no real idea unless you can show some relevant code.

Comment: It only acts like that when I move in angle like this. When I set camera directly into the cube and move from it - everything looks normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix my problem. I set:

```
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &matProj, D3DX_PI/4, (4.0f / 3.0f), 0.5f, 10000 );
```

to:

```
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &matProj, D3DX_PI/4, (4.0f / 3.0f), 1.0f, 1000 );
```

If the view distance is too small for you, better scale your objects, but do not increase your view distance while working at such basic stuff like me.